# CSS next elements until element without class

Tags: css

How to choose elements next after your element untill element without class
Example.

Clicking for 1st `<tr>`, I need here next `<tr>` elements with class `lvl-2`, untill last `<tr>`.

Comment: the last tr doesnt have a class ?

Comment: This question description is very confusing. Also please note, OP did not post the HTML

Comment: agree that the question is so **confusing** that I can't understand and maybe don't want to try to understand what you want.

Comment: Administrator, you fix my html but did it incorrect.  <tr></tr><tr class="lvl-2"></tr><tr class="lvl-2"></tr><tr></tr> this one correct

Comment: @VladimirShabuniayeu it's not administrator, anyone having enough reputation can edit your question :) but it can be rolled back by you or someone else.

Comment: But i can't edit html part right now

Comment: @VladimirShabuniayeu you can edit your question with your html, there is a button for code, highlight your html then press the code button `{}` I beleive

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
tr#id + tr.lvl-2{/* Styles */}
tr.lvl-2 + tr.lvl-2{/*Styles*/}
```

Check updated @aelor's fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2p3TN/2/

Comment: what should i put for the id ?

Comment: Not necessarily, just some way to identify the element where you want to start.

Comment: can you please check here and tell where am i going wrong ? http://jsfiddle.net/YL44Y/

Comment: @aelor your fiddle html is invalid, `tr` is an element within a table and text need to be inside of `td` see http://jsfiddle.net/YL44Y/1/

Comment: @GuillermoGutiérrez thanks man , can you explain a bit why you whave written two lines.

Comment: @GuillermoGutiérrez just a heads up, aelor is not the OP. Of course helping others is cool

Comment: Just found that the combinator `+` only takes the inmediate next fiddle (http://css-tricks.com/child-and-sibling-selectors/), so I added the second to apply the style to the next rows that contains `lvl-2` class, and that follow a row that has that class.

Comment: @Huangism, you are right, I got confused. But also I think that maybe is an approach the OP could try. Waiting for a comment if it is or is not what OP needs.

Comment: +1 i dont know what the op needs but i learnt something today